# Как прописать путь в Javascript?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста! Как прописать путь к файлам в javascript?!

```
Пример как он в оригинале: L.path='http://stud.ru/load/'
```

Но мне нужно прописать путь на сервере до файлов в папке, где они лежат!

```
такой вариант у меня не прокатил: L.path='<a href="../servis-catalog/load">'
```

Помогите разобраться!

Comment: Путь на сервере до файлов в папке - это /home/username/site.ru/servis-catalog/load.php, например? Или что? По какому адресу размещена страница, где не прокатил второй вариант с относительным адресом гиперссылки?

Comment: относительный адрес вещь странная. попробуй `<a href="/path/to/files">` 
просто `/path/to/files` - считает путь от корня сайта. 

`./path/to/files`- считает путь от текущего каталога, из которого запущен скрипт. 

`../path/to/files` - сичтает путь от каталога уровнем выше

Comment: Нашел! Спасибо за советы!

    L.path='../img-galery/'

Answer (score 3):

Ответ из комментариев:

Нужно формировать относительный путь до нужного файла:
`/path/to/files` - считает путь от корня сайта.
`./path/to/files` - считает путь от текущего каталога, из которого запущен скрипт.
`../path/to/files` - сичтает путь от каталога уровнем выше